# How to prove "A finite saturated chain is maximal if and only if it contains both a minimal and a maximal element of the poset"

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, relations, order-theory

The [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glossary_of_order_theory#M) says:

> Maximal chain. A chain in a poset to which no element can be added without losing the property of being totally ordered. This is stronger than being a saturated chain, as it also excludes the existence of elements **either less than all** elements of the chain or greater than all its elements. A finite saturated chain is maximal if and only if it contains **both a minimal and a maximal** element of the poset.

Q:

But the minimal element **may be incomparable** since its definition only ensures "not greater than any other", then why does one finite saturated **chain** need to contain **both a minimal and a maximal** element to become maximal?

**Edited**:

After reading some comments, I have questions about

> A finite saturated chain is maximal if and only if it contains **both a minimal and a maximal** element of the poset.

As the comment says, for one finite saturated chain $0 < 1$ based on the relation $<$ on the subset $\{x\in\mathbb{N}\vert -N\le x\le N\}$ of the set $\mathbb{N}$, after adding "both a minimal and a maximal element", i.e. $\{-N,N\}$, the chain $-N < 0 < 1 < N$ is **not maximal**. Then it seems that one half of the statement "A finite saturated chain is maximal if it contains both a minimal and a maximal element of the poset." is wrong.

Could someone give one proof of this or offer some hints?

Comment: Because a finite chain always has a smallest and largest element.  If the chain is maximal, its smallest element is a minimal element, and its largest element is a maximal element.

Comment: @ChadK Since [one finite poset has one maximal element](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/436035/1059606), do you mean that this finite chain already has one minimal element, similarly for the maximal element, so **vacuously** a **finite** saturated chain is **already** maximal?

Comment: No, a finite saturated chain doesn't have to be maximal.  For example, in $1<2<3<4$ then $\{2,3\}$ is saturated, but not maximal.

Comment: @ChadK Could I understand what you said as that if we have one finite chain $P$ with the largest element $m_1$ and smallest element $m_2$ and and one finite saturated chain $T\subseteq P$, then $T\cup \{m_1,m_2\}$ by adding $m_1,m_2$ in their corresponding appropriate locations is maximal?

Comment: No, there could be other holes between $T$ and $P$.  For example the integers $-N, -N+1,\ldots,0,\ldots,N-1,N$.  Then $\{0,1\}$ is a saturated chain, but $\{-N,0,1,N\}$ is not maximal - there are other holes - $-1, 2$, etc.

Comment: @ChadK (I delete one ambiguous comment and add this comment based on that.) Since my 2nd comment is the "if" part based on the assumption of "A finite saturated chain", from your 3rd comment, this statement seems to be wrong. Then could you give one proof of "A finite saturated chain is maximal if and only if it contains both a minimal and a maximal element of the poset." when you have some time? Or could you give more hints about "if" part and I will try to do the "only if" part after understanding the "if" part? I will update my question. Thanks for comments and possible answer beforehand.

Comment: The chain $-N < 0 < 1 < N$ is not saturated, either.

Comment: @MishaLavrov Thanks for the comment. You are right. Do I have some misunderstanding of the statement from wikipedia? (probably some misunderstanding)